# Amazon Web Services read-only account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, readonly, account

Is there an option to grant read-only access to an Amazon Web Services (AWS) account?

What I'd like to achieve is to be able to see instances and configurations without having to log in as a user who has administrative permissions to avoid accidental changes.

Comment: did you try searching for "aws read only" on your favorite search engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. An AWS Account cannot be made "read-only".

However, you can create a User in Identity and Access Management (IAM) and assign them "Read Only" permissions, which means they can interact with AWS but cannot change anything. However, this would still require that they login or at least use a set of credentials with calling the API or using the [Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

If your main goal is to avoid accidental changes, try this:

- Create a **User** in IAM who has minimal permissions (eg read-only, and probably also permissions to create new resources such as buckets and instances)
- Create a **Role** in IAM that has elevated permissions
- Setup the User with the ability to "**assume**" the Role within the web browser

This way, the User won't have 'dangerous' permissions unless they specifically request it. A visual indication then shows when they are using this alternate role (which can also grant access to a different AWS Account).

For details, see:

- Blog: [Cross-Account Access in the AWS Management Console](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-cross-account-access-in-the-aws-management-console/)
- Article: [Enable a New Feature in the AWS Management Console: Cross-Account Access](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx2MUS2R3CMGG8H/Enable-a-New-Feature-in-the-AWS-Management-Console-Cross-Account-Access)